# Animation working only once

Tags: android, animation

I'm trying to animate an ImageButton so that it would move a little each time it's clicked. For some reasons though, the animation work only once.

Code:

```
public void ballClicked(View v) {

        imgBtn.clearAnimation();
        imgBtn.animate().translationX(50).setDuration(500).start();
        imgBtn.animate().translationY(50).setDuration(500).start();

        oldX = oldX+50;
        oldY = oldY+50;
        imgBtn.setClickable(false);

        // Using this as Animation Listener doesn't trigger when the animation finish
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                imgBtn.setX((float)oldX+50);
                imgBtn.setY((float)oldY+50);
                imgBtn.setClickable(true);
            }
        }, 500);

    }`
```

Comment: do u want to animate according to time or according to click. Means at specific time animation should happen or when user clicks ?

Comment: @Slamit check my answer ^_^

Comment: I want to animate according to clic. the post delay is here as I can't make the animation handler work here were it work on another class ...
@Charu, I'll try that when Adroid Studio is done updating :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work!

```
public void ballClicked(View v) {

    imgBtn.clearAnimation();

    oldX = oldX + 50;
    oldY = oldY + 50;

    imgBtn.animate().translationX(oldX).setDuration(500).start();
    imgBtn.animate().translationY(oldY).setDuration(500).start();

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            imgBtn.setX((float) oldX + 50);
            imgBtn.setY((float) oldY + 50);

        }
    }, 500);


}
```

Comment: That would mean that the value taken by translationX is based on the original position, it doesn'tmake sence to me but I'll try.

Comment: @Slamit it makes perfect sence and it should move try and let me know what you did was second move and others moves were for the same position so you won't see any animation right after the first one.

Comment: Ok reading the doc I get it indeed (I should ready it more often ...): translationX property to be animated to the specified value. So I should but my coord there. thanks for the help. Bets would be translationByX in my case then.